# When a constructor failure happens, what clean up must be made?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am currently writing an implementation for classic data structures such as *search trees*. I am beginning with the B+ trees.

The class involved look like this :

```cpp
template <typename Key, typename Record>
class BPlusNode {
    /* ... */
}

template <typename Key, typename Record>
class BPlusINode : public BPlusNode<Key, Record> {
    /* ... */
}

template <typename Key, typename Record>
class BPlusLeaf : public BPlusNode<Key, Record> {
    /* ... */
}
template <typename Key, typename Record>
class BPlusTree {
    /* ... */
private:
    BPlusNode<Key, Record> *root;
    /* ... */
}
```

I am writing the copy constructor for my tree. It is a bit complicated since it involves a BFS search on the original tree to copy each node one by one (and edit the children and parent pointers accordingly). A memory allocation failure (or anything else bad) can happen at some point during the copying process. As a result I must throw an exception to signal that the object creation failed. But what will happen to all the nodes I have created ? Will they automatically be destroyed or do I have to clean up the mess ?

**EDIT :** Some precisions about the copy constructor

```cpp
template <typename Key, typename Record>
BPlusTree<Key, Record>::BPlusTree(BPlusTree<Key, Record> &tree) {
    std::list<BPlusNode<Key, Record>*> to_cpy;
    BPlusNode<Key, Record> *n = nullptr, *p = nullptr, *cpy = nullptr;
    to_cpy.push_back(tree.root);
    while (!to_cpy.empty()) {
        n = to_cpy.front();
        n.listChildren(to_cpy) // Push all @n's children at the back of @to_cpy
                               // (In order)
        to_cpy.pop_front();
        cpy = n.clone(); // May fail.
        /*
         * Some mechanisms to track who is the parent node for @cpy
         * and to edit the children pointers when all have been copied
         */
    }
}
```

*Bonus question :* I keep the root as a pointer because when the tree evolves, since B+ tree do not grow from top to bottom but from bottom to top, the root can change. Is it the *right* solution ? (By right, I mean the most C++-esque)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the constructor fails, the destructors of all fully
constructed sub-objects are called, but not the destructor of
the object whose constructor failed.

The classic way of handling this (used by all of the
implementations of `std::vector` that I've seen, for example)
put the memory management in a private base class, something
like:

```
class TreeBase
{
    Note* root;
    friend class Tree;
    TreeBase() : root( nullptr ) {}
    ~TreeBase() { delete root; }  //  Or whatever is needed for cleanup.
};
```

Since this base class will be fully constructed before you enter
into the actual constructor code of the tree, its destructor
will be called.

And there's no problem with changing `root`, as long as the
structure accessible through `root` remains coherent enough to
allow proper clean-up.  And even this constraint can be loosed
for short intervals in which you are sure that no exceptions can
be raised.  (While rebalancing the tree, for example; that
operation only involves pointer manipulations, which can never
raise an exception.)

Comment: What is disturbing me here is that the process to copy a tree and to delete are at the same level of abstraction. This would mean that my base class would be able 1. to copy, 2. to delete any tree (with the proper virtual methods defined by the subclasses). If I get it right, the solution is to "split" this base into 2 classes, the super handling the destruction and the sub handling the copy ?

Comment: I finally applied the spirit of your solution differently. My destructor uses a private clean up method. I surround the critical code in the copy constructor with a try-catch and call the cleanup method in the catch to do the job. Your answer has put me on the good track so I'll accept it. Thanks !

Comment: @Rerito The base class doesn't copy anything.  It contains the root pointer, which it initializes to a null pointer, and does _nothing_ else except in the destructor.  All of the copying, building, etc. take place in the derived class.  (Done correctly, you shouldn't need a try/catch at all.)

Comment: The private base class works on the same principle as my "manager" that manages it for you and is fully constructed

Comment: After considering this design, shouldn't the member of this private nested class be declared public to be easily accessed through the tree's methods?

Comment: @Rerito It depends.  In private nested members, I'll often make it a `struct`, will all members public.  As a base class, like here, I might make them protected, or I might provide accessors; there's no absolute rule.  (The inheritance will normally be private, so that client code of the tree won't see the base.)

Answer (score 4):

If your constructor throws the destructor will not be called.

Therefore anything you have created at that point that relies on the destructor to clean-up must be cleaned up by you.

Object members that have been constructed in the initialiser list prior to the exception will be cleaned up with their destructors. So if, for example, your class contains some smart-pointers, the clean-up will occur.

Your question of "will the subnodes be destructed"? If they are stored in smart-pointers or similar objects. The nodes can have a weak link back to their parent.

If you are not able to store smart pointers in your class, and rely on your destructor to delete, then use a smart pointer in the constructor itself, up to the point where you know it will no longer throw. You can use `std::unique_ptr` if available or `std::auto_ptr` if that is all you have. Either way you assign it to the class member pointer with `release`. If you need them in a vector, say, then `unique_ptr` is useful as you can store those in a (temporary) vector, then run through and call `release` on all of them at the end.

Otherwise if you don't want an implicit two-stage construction, do it behind the scenes.

```
class ChildNodeManager
{
    friend class Node; // this implements detail of Node

    ChildNodeManager() {} // constructor that never throws, might initialise 
       // some pointers to nullptr.

    void addNode( Node * node ); // might throw but will leave in a stable state
         // if it does, i.e. how it was before you tried addNode. Destructor 
         // will work safely

     ~ChildNodeManager() { // do cleanup of added nodes }

    // probably disable copy construction and assignment
};

class Node
{
   ChildNodeManager myChildren;

   public:
      Node( ... ) // might throw

};
```

As ChildNodeManager is a fully constructed member in the body of Node's constructor, it will be properly destroyed even if the constructor of Node fails somewhere in the middle. Any nodes already added to it will be cleaned up.

Comment: Smart pointers are an obvious solution, at least if he doesn't need back pointers to the parent (otherwise, making some pointers strong and some weak introduces a lot of extra, unnecessary complexity).  It's not necessarily a good solution, because it locks you into one specific memory management scheme; one that is typically not the best for tree structures.  There's a reason why smart pointers aren't normally used in the implementation of the standard containers, for example.

Comment: As you stated @JamesKanze, I read about smart pointers and I thought it would be very complicated with all the pointer editing I must do while rebalancing the tree, with insertion/deletion and all the editing that may arise (parent and children pointers).

Comment: I edited the question to give a slight view of the current copy constructor (with no clean-up operation for now).

Comment: I have expanded my solution to show how you can manage it using a separate class to manage the child nodes, and for that class you use 2 phase construction, i.e. first construct, then add the nodes. As it is fully constructed, it will definitely destruct.

Comment: @Rerito If you don't need a pointer to parent, the smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr`) isn't that difficult.  It is relatively inefficient, however, and constrains future evolution (e.g. adding a pointer to parent becomes more difficult, and changing from a tree to an arbitrary graph almost impossible).